# Bootstrap select with values and option to create new value

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, select

I want a select field with predefined options from database and allow user to either select from predefined options or to create a new value if suitable value is not in the list.

I'm using Bootstrap 3

and creating select field using ajax like

```
  /*
  * select product attributes on change of product type
  */
  $("#producttypes").on('change',function() {
     var id = $(this).val();

     $("#product_attributes").html('');
     if (id) {
       var dataString = 'id='+ id;
       $.ajax({
           dataType:'json',
           type: "POST",
           url: '/products/ajax-get-product-attribute-types' ,
           data: dataString,
           cache: false,
           success: function(data) {
              var i = 0;
              $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                var message = '<div class="form-group">' +
                              '<label>'+value['title']+'</label>' +
                              '<input type="hidden" name="product_attribute_type_title[]" value="'+value['value']+'" />' +
                              '<select name="product_attribute_value[]" class="form-control select2" style="width:100%">';

                         $.each(value['product_attributes'], function(a, b) {
                           message += '<option value="'+b['value']+'">'+b['value']+'</option>';
                })

                message += '</select>' +
                        '</div>';
                $('#product_attributes').append(message);
                i = i+1;
            });
         },
         error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
             alert(xhr.status);
             alert(thrownError);
         }
      });
    }
  });
```

In short, I want a combination of `input type="text"` and `select` tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this after your ajax call

```
$(".select2").append('<option value="">Other</option>');
$(".select2").on("change", function(){
 if(this.value=="")
  $(".othertxt").removeClass("hidden").focus();
 else
  $(".othertxt").addClass("hidden");
});
```

and in the html add

```
<input type="text" class="hidden othertxt">
```

now i guess, it answers ur question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 /*
  * select product attributes on change of product type
  */
  $("#producttypes").on('change',function() {
     var id = $(this).val();

     $("#product_attributes").html('');
     if (id) {
       var dataString = 'id='+ id;
       $.ajax({
           dataType:'json',
           type: "POST",
           url: '/products/ajax-get-product-attribute-types' ,
           data: dataString,
           cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                  var i = 0;
                  $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                    var message = '<div class="form-group">' +
                                  '<label>'+value['title']+'</label>' +
                                  '<input type="hidden" name="product_attribute_type_title[]" style="display:none;" class="product_attribute_type_title" value="'+value['value']+'" />' +
                                  '<select name="product_attribute_value[]" class="form-control select2" style="width:100%">';

                             $.each(value['product_attributes'], function(a, b) {
                               message += '<option value="'+b['value']+'">'+b['value']+'</option>';
                    })

                    message += '<option value="others">Others</option></select>' +
                            '</div>';
                    $('#product_attributes').append(message);
            // change events
            $(".select2").on("change",function(){
            if($(this).val() == "others")
               {$(this).find(".product_attribute_type_title").css("display","none");
$(this).find(".product_attribute_type_title").focus();
               }});

                    i = i+1;
                });
         },
         error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
             alert(xhr.status);
             alert(thrownError);
         }
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: try something like this.

Comment: I tried this but `onchange` is not working on code generated by jQuery. Same is working fine if select field is predefined in html